# modifying datatable column value if it satisfies a statement

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

I have a datatable with columns: Username, Password and Score.

I get score after finishing a quiz(QuizForm), then I should log in with username and password and save score if it's higher then the previous one.

I did this but I guess it's wrong

```
static public void SaveScore(string username, string score) 
{
    try 
    {
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
        db.Connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cmdWrite = db.GetCommand("insert into Users(Username, Password) values(username, password)");
        SqlCommand cmdRead = db.GetCommand("select * from Users");

        SqlDataReader reader = cmdRead.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows) {
            while (reader.Read()) {
                if (username == reader["Username"].ToString() && int.Parse(score) > Convert.ToInt32(reader["Score"])) {
                    cmdWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"Score", score);
                }
            }
        }
        db.Connection.Close();


    }
    catch (SqlException ex) {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

it isn't saving score.
any ideas how to fix it?

P.S. `GetCommand` looks like this:

```
public SqlCommand GetCommand(string CommandText){
        var cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = Connection;
        cmd.CommandText = CommandText;
        return cmd;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem.

here it is:

```
static public void SaveScore(string username, string score) {
        try {
            DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();
            db.Connection.Open();
            var cmd = db.GetCommand("SELECT Score FROM Users WHERE Username = username");
            var oldScore = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
            var value = Int32.Parse(score);
            if (oldScore < value) {
                cmd = db.GetCommand("UPDATE Users SET Score = @score WHERE Username = @username AND Score < @score");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", value);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
                MessageBox.Show("New High Score Was Saved","Congratulations",MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }
            else {
                MessageBox.Show("High Score Wasn't Reached. Try Again", "Game Over", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            db.Connection.Close();                
        }
        catch (SqlException ex) {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your cmdWrite is not including the Score column:

```
SqlCommand cmdWrite = db.GetCommand("insert into Users(Username, Password) values(username, password)");
```

Should be like this:

```
SqlCommand cmdWrite = db.GetCommand("insert into Users(Username, Password, Score) values(@username, @password, @score)");
```

And then:

```
cmdWrite.Parameters.AddWithValue("@score", score);
```